# Outlook add-in ribbon Icon

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I am trying to upload my outlook add-in but I get a rejection from Microsoft, that my ribbon icon can't be the default icon.
[image: microsoft rejection]

but I am quite of sure that I have done everything right on my manifest:

```
...

<IconUrl DefaultValue="https://outlook.rocalytics.net/assets/icon-80.png" />
...
<Control>
...
  <Icon>
    <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon16" />
    <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon32" />
    <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon80" />
  </Icon>
  ...
</Control>
...
<Resources>
  <bt:Images>
    <bt:Image id="icon16" DefaultValue="https://outlook.rocalytics.net/assets/icon-16.png"/>
    <bt:Image id="icon32" DefaultValue="https://outlook.rocalytics.net/assets/icon-32.png"/>
    <bt:Image id="icon80" DefaultValue="https://outlook.rocalytics.net/assets/icon-80.png"/>
  </bt:Images>
</Resources>
```

thanks for helping

Comment: SOS, HELP!!!  
anybody??

Comment: All those icon links return "Not Found"

Comment: Assuming that at one point the icon links worked, do they show up strange in Desktop Outlook 2016?

Comment: Someone forwarded me the correct link at: https://outlook.rocalytics.net/assets/icon80x80.png. I moved this file to another webserver, and it loaded fine in Outlook 2016. I checked with fiddler your file, and in the headers it is returning: Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache. The no-cache flag prevents desktop applications from downloading/saving the file to the app cache. There is no planned fix for this right now. The workaround is to remove the no-cache flag from the ribbon icons.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/add-in-manifests?tabs=tabid-1#hosting-requirements